# Clarification on Formulation of a DP Problem

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dynamic-programming

I am self-teaching reinforcement learning and for now I am trying to solve the following DP problem:

> A driver is looking for inexpensive parking on the way to his destination. The parking
> area contains $N$ spaces, and a garage at the end. The driver starts at space 0 and
> traverses the parking spaces sequentially, i.e., from space $k$ he goes next to space $k + 1$,
> etc. Each parking space $k$ costs $c(k)$ and is free with probability $p(k)$ independently
> of whether other parking spaces are free or not. If the driver reaches the last parking
> space $N − 1$ and does not park there, he must park at the garage, which costs $C$. The
> driver can observe whether a parking space is free only when he reaches it, and then, if
> it is free, he makes a decision to park in that space or not to park and check the next
> space. The problem is to find the minimum expected cost parking policy.

As a first step, I defined the state space at stage $i$ to be $S_i = \{1, ...,\min\{i, N\}\}$ (because $\min\{i, N\}$ is the farthest that the driver can reach), and the action space to be $A_i = \{0, 1\}$, where $0$ stands for the action of staying at the current space, and $1$ denotes moving on to the next space.

How am I supposed to define the state-reward distribution? At stage $i$, is it that
$$
\begin{cases}
p_i(s+1, c(s+1)\mid s, 1) = p(s+1)\\
p_i(s, c(s)\mid s, 0) = p(s)
\end{cases}\;(s < N),\quad p_i(s, C\mid s, 0) = 1\quad (s = N)?
$$

Comment: https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/75813/6-231-fall-2008/contents/exams/midterm_solution.pdf ?

Comment: Would you add your current idea of state and policy? You mentioned state of parking space. How about state of driver?

Comment: @CloudCho Oh I first wanted to define the driver's state via his location - but I ignored that his target was to park the car instead of reaching a certain parking space...

Comment: If the driver rewarded by parking his car in a parking spot. Is his goal the max rewarding parking spot (cheapest one) or park, pull out and park in different spots to increase rewards?

Comment: @CloudCho The driver simply stops at where he decides to park.